# how to deliver string via p/invoke?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I need to deliver a string via p/invoke, it's just a filename, something like "desc.xml".
I don't care if it would be `std::string` or `char*` or probably something else (i can convert to appropiate type). How should I declare signatures?

On c# side I expect for something like that:

```
    [DllImport("Native.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern void Initialize(/*TODO: how to pass string?*/);
```

On c++ side I expect something like that:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void Initialize(char* fileName);
```

or `std::string` instead of `char*`

```
__declspec(dllexport) void Initialize(std::string& fileName);
```

I expect it to use like that:

```
Initialize("desc.xml");
```

The question is how exactly should I declare parameters.

Comment: Did you try using .Net's String class? [That's what to use for Winapi](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowText).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to receive ANSI encoded text, you should declare the C++ code like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void Initialize(const char* fileName);
```

This will use the default calling convention of `__cdecl`. The text will be passed as a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char`.

On the C# side you declare it like this:

```
[DllImport("Native.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Initialize(string fileName);
```

There's no need to specify the character set since the default is `ANSI. If you want to be explicit (not a bad idea in my view) then you can write it like this:

```
[DllImport("Native.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
    CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void Initialize(string fileName);
```

If you compile the C++ code as is the function's name will be mangled. You'd have to use the `EntryPoint` parameter of the `DllImport` attribute to specify the mangled name. As an alternative you could wrap up the native code's declaration of the function in an `extern "C"` block to suppress mangling.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static extern void Initialize(string filename);
```

Also add a [CharSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset.aspx) to your `DllImport("Native.dll")` to match what you have on the C++ side (`CharSet.Ansi` for `char*`, `CharSet.Unicode` for `wchar*`).